# An uncaught Exception was encountered Type: Error Message: Class 'BaseController' not found

Tags: php, web-crawler

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

class index extends BaseController
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('P_pmb', 'p_pmb');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data['title'] = 'Dashboard';
        $this->render('index/index', $data);
    }

    public function pendaftarprodi1()
    {
        $data['title'] = 'Grafik Berdasarkan Prodi 1';
        $prodi = $this->p_pmb->listProdi();
        foreach ($prodi as $key => $p) {
            $prodi[$key]['jumlah'] = $this->p_pmb->jumlahPendaftarProdi1($p['id_prodi']);
            $prodi[$key]['jumlah2'] = $this->p_pmb->jumlahPendaftarProdi2($p['id_prodi']);
            $prodi[$key]['size'] = rand(10, 30);
        }

        //grafik 1
        $result = null;
        foreach ($prodi as $p => $prod) {
            // if ($prod['jumlah'] > $sum) {
            //     $sum = $prod['jumlah'];
            //     $sliced = true;
            //     $selected = true;
            // }
            $result[$p] = [
                "name"  => $prod['nama_prodi'],
                "jumlah" => $prod['jumlah'],
                "y"     => $prod['size'],
                // "sliced" => $sliced,
                // 'selected' => $selected
            ];
        }

        $data['pendaftar'] = $prodi;
        $data['grafik1'] = json_encode($result);
        $this->render('index/grafik1', $data);
    }

    public function pendaftarprodi2()
    {
        $data['title'] = 'Grafik Berdasarkan Prodi 2';
        $prodi = $this->p_pmb->listProdi();
        foreach ($prodi as $key => $p) {
            $prodi[$key]['jumlah'] = $this->p_pmb->jumlahPendaftarProdi1($p['id_prodi']);
            $prodi[$key]['jumlah2'] = $this->p_pmb->jumlahPendaftarProdi2($p['id_prodi']);
            $prodi[$key]['size'] = rand(10, 30);
        }

        //grafik 2
        $hasil = null;
        foreach ($prodi as $p => $prod) {
            $hasil[$p] = [
                "name"  => $prod['nama_prodi'],
                "jumlah" => $prod['jumlah2'],
                "y"     => $prod['size'],
                // "sliced" => $sliced,
                // 'selected' => $selected
            ];
        }

        $data['pendaftar'] = $prodi;
        $data['grafik2'] = json_encode($hasil);
        $this->render('index/grafik2', $data);
    }
    public function pendaftarprestasi()
    {

        $pendaftarprestasi = $this->p_pmb->listpendaftarprestasi();
        foreach ($pendaftarprestasi as $key => $p) {
            $pendaftarprestasi[$key]['jumlah'] = $this->p_pmb->jumlahpendaftarprestasi($p['tingkat_prestasi']);
            $pendaftarprestasi[$key]['size'] = rand(10, 30);
        }

        $result = null;
        $sum = 0;
        foreach ($pendaftarprestasi as $p => $pendpres) {
            //if ($pendpres['jumlah'] > $sum) {
            //   $sum = $pendpres['jumlah'];
            //  $sliced = true;
            //  $selected = true;
            // }
            $result[$p] = [
                "name"  => $pendpres['tingkat_prestasi'],
                'jumlah' => $pendpres['jumlah'],
                'y'     => $pendpres['size'],
                //    $sliced => $sliced,
                //   $selected => $selected
            ];
        }

        $data['pendaftarprestasi'] = $pendaftarprestasi;
        $data['grafikprestasi'] = json_encode($result);
        $this->render('index/grafikprestasi', $data);
    }
    public function jalurmasuk()
    {

        $pendaftar = $this->p_pmb->listjalurpendaftar();
        foreach ($pendaftar as $key => $p) {
            $pendaftar[$key]['jumlah'] = $this->p_pmb->jumlahjalurpendaftar($p['nama_jalur']);
            $pendaftar[$key]['jumlah'] = rand(10, 30);
        }

        $result = null;
        $sum = 0;
        foreach ($pendaftar as $p => $jalmask) {
            //if ($jalmask['jumlah'] > $sum) {
            //   $sum = $jalmask['jumlah'];
            //  $sliced = true;
            //  $selected = true;
            // }
            $result[$p] = [
                "name"  => $jalmask['nama_jalur'],
                'jumlah' => $jalmask['jumlah'],
                'y'     => $jalmask['jumlah'],
                //    $sliced => $sliced,
                //   $selected => $selected
            ];
        }

        $data['jalur_masuk'] = $jalmask;
        $data['grafikmasuk'] = json_encode($result);
        $this->render('index/grafikmasuk', $data);
    }
    public function pendapatan()
    {
        $data['title'] = 'Grafik Pendapatan Berdasarkan Bank';
        $bank = $this->p_pmb->listBank();
        $pendaftar = $this->p_pmb->pendaftarBank();

        $categories = null;
        $lunas = null;
        $belum_lunas = null;
        $sumTotal = 0;
        foreach ($bank as $i => $b) {
            $categories[] = $b['bank'];
            foreach ($pendaftar as $key => $value) {
                if ($b['id_bank'] == $value['id_bank']) {
                    if ($value['is_bayar'] == '1') {
                        $sumTotal += intval($value['total']);
                        $lunas[] = intval($value['total']);
                    } else {
                        $belum_lunas[] = intval($value['total']);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $result[] = [
            'name' => 'Pendapatan',
            'data' => $lunas,
        ];
        $data['subtitle'] = 'Total Pendapatan Rp.' . $sumTotal;
        $grafik['id_bank'] = json_encode($result);
        $grafik['categories'] = json_encode($categories);
        $data['grafikpendapatan'] = $grafik;
        $this->render('index/grafikpendapatan', $data);
    }
    public function bank()
    {
        $data['title'] = 'Grafik Pendapatan Berdasarkan Bank';
        $bank = $this->p_pmb->listBank();
        $pendaftar = $this->p_pmb->pendaftarBank();

        $categories = null;
        $lunas = null;
        $belum_lunas = null;
        $sumTotal = 0;
        foreach ($bank as $i => $b) {
            $categories[] = $b['bank'];
            foreach ($pendaftar as $key => $value) {
                if ($b['id_bank'] == $value['id_bank']) {
                    if ($value['is_bayar'] == '1') {
                        $sumTotal += intval($value['total']);
                        $lunas[] = intval($value['total']);
                    } else {
                        $sumTotal += $value['jumlah'];
                        $belum_lunas[] = intval($value['total']);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $result[] = [
            'name' => 'Lunas',
            'data' => $lunas,
        ];
        $result[] = [
            'name' => 'Belum Lunas',
            'data' => $belum_lunas,
        ];
        $data['subtitle'] = 'Total Pendaftar: ' . $sumTotal;
        $data['id_bank'] = $bank;
        $data['grafikbank'] = json_encode($result);
       $this->render('index/grafikbank', $data);
    }
}




<?php
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

class BaseController extends CI_Controller
{

    public function render($filename, $data)
    {
        $this->load->view('template/app_top', $data);
        $this->load->view('template/template_scripts', $data);
        $this->load->view($filename, $data);
        $this->load->view('template/app_bottom', $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: The code is unformatted and unreadable. You may want to use edit to add code tags around that. And perhaps adding some explanation or context, etc.

Comment: Do you use Composer autoload? If not, are index class, BaseController class and CI_Controller declared in separate files?

Comment: what code to add?